# Toast every X seconds

Tags: android, delay, android-toast

I have a function that gets executed every 0.~2 seconds (due to lag). However, I would like to perform a toast every 5 seconds. May i know how I can achieve this ?

```
 public void navigation(Coordinate userPosition , Coordinate destination){
     if (Math.abs(userPosition.y - destination.y) > 500) {
     {Toast.makeText(this, "Walk for " + Math.abs(CheckPoint.y - UserPosition.y) + "mm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }
 }
```

Above is a sample of my current code. The frequency of which the toast gets executed is dependent on the current 'lag'. I would like the toast to be sent every 5 seconds minimum.

Comment: use timertask or alarm manager

Comment: Please consider accepting and answer. It could be useful for others having the same question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            navigation(...);
            handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
        }
    }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this for exactly five second,

```
 int count = 100; //Declare as inatance variable

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(), --count + "",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            toast.cancel();
                        }
                    }, 5000);

                }
            });
        }
    }, 0, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Thread and loop that thread

```
    Thread myThread = null;

    Runnable runnable = new CountDownRunner();
            myThread = new Thread( runnable );
            myThread.start();



    class CountDownRunner implements Runnable
       {
          // @Override
           public void run()
            {
              while( !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() )
               {
                 try
                 {
                    navigation(); // do the work here 
                    Thread.sleep( 2000 );  // time interval for the counter. it will run every 2 sec
                }
                catch( InterruptedException e )
                {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
                catch( Exception e )
                {
                }
            }
        }
    }

   public void navigation(Coordinate userPosition , Coordinate destination){
     if (Math.abs(userPosition.y - destination.y) > 500) {
     {Toast.makeText(this, "Walk for " + Math.abs(CheckPoint.y - UserPosition.y) + "mm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with a loop `Thread`? Try it out:

```
private Thread loopThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       while(true){
          try {
              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                     Toast.makeText(this, "Your text!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              });   
              Thread.Sleep(5000); //Wait 5 seconds, then repeat!     
           }catch (Exception e) {
                  return;
           }catch (InterruptedException i) {
                  return;
           }
        }
    }
});
```

Then start the `Thread` wherever you want like:

```
Thread myThread = new Thread(loopThread);
myThread.start();
```

And stop it with:

```
myThread.interrupt();
```

Hope it helps!